# What does Permission denied to access object in Firebug's console (Firebug is a FF addon) using Firefox 17 (latest) version?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery, cross-browser

just wondering if someone have found seeing the following error in the firebug console, or any idea of what could it mean?? 
Does this has to do with a browser thing when having the same page opened in two tabs or something?? 
Have you fixed a similar problem?? 
What would be a way of ensuring this error is not thrown, is annoying to me :(

Would it have to be with the fact that the site requires cookies, javascript or any considerations you could suggest??

```
Error: Permission denied to access object

Error: Permission denied to access object

Error:

Error: Permission denied to access object

Error: Permission denied to access object

Error:
```

Reproducibility:
(6 errors in the console listed when loading a page in two tabs with FF)
Haven't tried other browsers.. This error appears to be unobtrusive, it does not stop any code from continuing, but I would love to get rid of it, or prevent it.. Thanks in advance for the help!! Much appreciated

Edit:

[image: This is the error mentioned above]

And now I get a new one, which might be the cause of the problem :(

**Error in Protected Function !281**

[image]

In addition:

@Pointy:
- yeah, Tested on FF 18. You are absolutely correct on that statement by the way ;) Thanks for the sanity check :)

[image: FF18]

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling other plugins and going fresh with FB only?  The console might be listing errors from other plugins.  Otherwise, nothing really comes to mind.  You can tell FB to break on next error and see if it breaks on one of those so you can step through where it's happening.  Of course if it's firebug itself doing this, you won't hit any breakpoints.

Comment: Possibly accessing an object from a frame with different origin.

Comment: Also Firefox 18 is out :-)

Comment: no, no frames.. the only instance in which this project uses an iframe is when calling a function with AJAX called doAjaxUpload which creates an iframe only for transporting a file upload and I am not even triggering that.. but thanks for the idea of where to look.. +1 for that Musa

Comment: @Pointy: FF latest.. yesterday it prompted me to actually upgrade :(

Comment: @Musa: No Cross-d0main calls here by the way.. please take a look at the attached screenshot.. :)

Comment: Ah - well as to your error, I agree with the suggestion about turning off plugins etc - a quick way to try that is to create a new empty profile. Do you also see the error in the "native" error console?

Comment: made an edit just a moment ago, hope that it helps... no, there is nothing else and as mentioned above, it does not stop any further processing, nor AJAXED calls nor jQuery.. everything is working just fine.. Can't turn off the plugins sorry, it's a really complex site to be used internally.. but I do appreciate your suggestions :)